# USB Devices not mounting in Mac OS 11.1 Big Sur

Tags: usb, launchd, mount, big-sur

I can't get USB devices to mount to my MacBook Pro (mid ‘14) unless they are plugged in at the time it boots. Even then the device can't be re-mounted after being removed. I've tried this with a flash drive, an external hard drive, and an SD card all with the same results.

I've also tried with and without a USB hub. Nothing appears on the desktop, nothing appears in Disk Utility, and nothing is showing up in System Profiler.

I had initially thought the issue was with the `diskarbitrationd` daemon, but that appears to be running

`sudo launchctl list | grep diskarbitrationd`
returns `86    0    com.apple.diskpaced`, and `ps aux | grep diskarbitrationd` returns an entry for `/usr/libexec/diskarbitrationd` running as root...

At this point I'm not sure what the issue is, so any help is appreciated.

Obviously rebooting with devices connected is a workaround, but not a great one.
FWIW I've tried a PRAM reset and a SMC reset just in case, to no avail. All thoughts are welcome!